# how can i send photo, caption and 2 inline button in single message telegram bot in php

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

[heres how i wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuvW7.png)

or like this https://t.me/RoobaiOfficaial/2032

i am new to coding and unable to get bot to working any help will be appreciated

code how i upload image and set chat id

```html
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="chat_id" value="" />
<input type="url" name="photo" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="send" action="<?php echo $website.'/sendPhoto'?>"/>
</form>
```

and i add message and create 1 inline button which contains url

```html
<?php



$msg= urlencode("test message");
$token="bot_token";
$chatId="chat_id";
$response=($_POST['photo']);
$response=$response.urldecode($msg);
$keyboard = [
    'inline_keyboard' => [
        [
            ['text' => 'Buy Now', 'url' => 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLHu9.png']

        ]
    ]

];
$encodedKeyboard = json_encode($keyboard);
$parameters = 
    array(
        'chat_id' => $chatId, 
        'text' => $response,
        'reply_markup' => $encodedKeyboard
    );

send('sendMessage', $parameters); // function description Below

function send($method, $data)
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/".$token. "/" . $method;

    if (!$curld = curl_init()) {
        exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($curld);
    curl_close($curld);
    return $output;
}
```

i m getting this type of response but i need it without link [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NVd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating these 2 lines:

```
send('sendMessage', $parameters); // function description Below

function send($method, $data)
```

to include $token

```
send('sendMessage', $parameters, $token); // function description Below

function send($method, $data, $token)
```

This link explains why its probably not working the way you expect it to.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: having a quick look at their api you might need to change "sendMessage" in your method to "sendPhoto" https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

Comment: i am getting sendMessage or sendPhoto at a time but i want both of them at single time

Comment: Add a caption parameter?